# Как убрать кракозябры при использовании русских символов в JSP?

Tags: java, кодировка, jsp, tomcat

У меня случилось так, что при интернационализации моего веб-проекта, русские символы отображаются кракозябрами.
Часть данных файла `locale_ru.properties`:

```
label.button.signIn=Вход
label.button.signUp=Регистрация
```

Что я делаю:

1. Я использую properties-файлы, в которых на нужном языке пишу текст. Нужно проверить, чтобы текст в данных файлах был установлен как `UTF-8`.

   Это не помогло. Идём дальше.
2. Через `Filter` задать кодировку `UTF-8`.

   Создаем фильтр, в котором будем устанавливать кодировку `UTF-8` для `request` и `response`:

   ```java
   @WebFilter(filterName = "EncodingFilter", urlPatterns = {"/controller"})
   public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {
       private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
       private final static String ENCODING_UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
           LOGGER.info("Current encoding for request: {}, for response: {}.", servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding(), servletResponse.getCharacterEncoding());
           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
           HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

           request.setCharacterEncoding(ENCODING_UTF_8);
           response.setCharacterEncoding(ENCODING_UTF_8);
           LOGGER.info("Set encoding for request: {}, for response: {}.", request.getCharacterEncoding(), response.getCharacterEncoding());

           filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
   }
   ```

   Но и это не помогло. Идём дальше.
3. Для каждой jsp-страницы нужно также задать кодировку `UTF-8`.

   Сделать это можно двумя способами:

   1. Прописав в `web.xml` файле настройки:

      ```xml
      <!-- Encoding for jsp-pages to UTF-8 -->
      <jsp-config>
          <jsp-property-group>
              <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
              <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
          </jsp-property-group>
      </jsp-config>
      ```
   2. Прописать на каждой jsp-странице:

      ```
      <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
      ```

   Но и это не помогло. Идём дальше.
4. Потом я, согласно [документации](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html), настроил `Tomcat` следующим образом.

   Открываем файл `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf\server.xml` и добавляем в секцию `<Connection>` атрибут `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`. В конечном итоге секция `<Connection>` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

   ```xml
   <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                  connectionTimeout="20000"
                  redirectPort="8443" 
                  URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
   ```

   Но и это не помогло. Перезагрузил ноутбук, думал поможет, но не заработало. Опять идём дальше.
5. Добавляем на jsp-страницу вот это:

   ```
   <%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%>
   ```

И это тоже не работает. Что ещё нужно сделать, ума не приложу?

**UPDATE 1:**
Выводится корректно, только если русский записать в таком формате:

```
\u041A\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043B\u043E\u0433
```

Что это за формат и зачем он такой нужен?

**UPDATE 2 (предыстория):**
Вот и баг `Intellij IDEA`.
Открываю я свой `locale_ru.properties` файл через `IntellijIDEA`, чтобы посмотреть кодировку данного файла, а в ответ вижу пустоту. Открываю теперь `locale_ru.properties` файл, смотрю внизу в окошку, где указывается кодировка и там она указана как `UTF-8`, но окошко недействительное, т.е. нельзя поменять кодировку. Перещелкиваю обратно на `locale_ru.properties` файл, а там уже такое же недействительно окно с надписью `UTF-8`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ок. Далее решил открыть с помощью `VS Code` и что я там вижу? Там стоит `UTF-8`! Что за бред? Да ещё и есть функция "Пересохранить с нужной кодировкой" (которая, естественно, не пересохранит):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE 3:**
Спасибо за наводки, почитав всё я понял, что есть два варианта:

1. Использовать конвертирующую утилиту `native2ascii`, которая будет преобразовывать текст:

```
Привет -> \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442
```

Почему не хочется это использовать? Открываю я свой properties файл и вижу там сплошное `\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442`, можно с ума сойти. А если что-то редактировать придется? Не вариант.
2) Создать свой класс на основе `ResourceBundle`, переопределив в нем кодировку таким образом:

```java
new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
```

Ок, допустим, я выбрал второй вариант, создал свой собственный класс `CustomResourceBundle`. Теперь как его использовать на JSP странице, если этот самый `ResourceBundle` задается следующим образом:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${sessionScope.locale_page}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="locale"/>
```

Comment: Посмотрите в этой статье в конце, похоже на ваш случай: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1557-konstantih-i-internacionalizacija

Comment: @insolor, ты гений! Наконец-то я понял, откуда копаться дальше.

Comment: @insolor, до сих пор сижу и не понимаю вот что. Почитай, пожалуйста, **UPDATE 3** в топике, я обновил.